# Moduli all the way down

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, constructive-mathematics

The notion of *modulus of continuity* is well-known from constructive mathematics, reverse mathematics, and computability theory.  Intuitively, such a modulus is a function that returns the '$\delta>0$' on input an '$\epsilon>0$' and a point in the domain.

In reverse mathematics, the second-order representation of continuous functions is equivalent to the existence of a **continuous** modulus of continuity, as shown by Kohlenbach.

I vaguely recall there being developments of (constructive?) mathematics where one considers continuous functions that come with a continuous modulus of continuity **and** a continuous modulus of continuity for the latter modulus.

Can someone provide a reference for the aforementioned construct?

EDIT: following a question, here is the formal statement of the second paragraph:

For any $Y:\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, the following are equivalent:

1. There is a total (Kleene) associate $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\alpha(f)=Y(f)$ for any $f\in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$,
2. There is a (second-order) RM-code $\Phi$, for which the value $\Phi(f)$ equals $Y(f)$ for any $f\in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$,
3. The functional $Y$ has a modulus of continuity.

See Section 4 in "FOUNDATIONAL AND MATHEMATICAL USES OF HIGHER TYPES" by Kohlenbach.

Comment: Could you provide a complete statement (I mean, with all the quantifiers explicitly written out) and a reference for the result by Kohlenbach that you mention in your second paragraph? I'm trying to understand exactly what this means.

Comment: I have a very vague memory of listening to a talk by Henri Lombardi in Dagstuhl in the previous millenium? He was lamenting about continuity not being well defined because moduli of contunuity had to be continuous. But my memory could be wrong.

Comment: Perhaps the following is what you are looking for?   https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.13203.pdf

Comment: @AliEnayat That is the kind of thing I  was looking for!  Thanks a lot.